Saml integration in servant or scotty app
Are there any libraries to integrate saml authentication in your backend app.
I will be developing a back end app (hopefully with servant) but I need to do saml authentication with an idp already setup in the company. it will be SP initiated authentication.
When I searched around I found hsaml2 and wai-saml2. These are the only ones I could find.
Does anybody have any experience using Haskell with saml authentication, if yes how did you go about it?
What problems you faced and how, if at all, you overcame them.
Thanks

We don't do "tell your story" poll kind of questions here.
